# What becomes different for a client after the command STARTTLS is sent and a response received

Tags: ssl, imap

I'm trying to understand how the command STARTTLS in IMAP works exactly and what becomes different when it's sent. **After I've sent the command "STARTTLS" before login process and received the response "OK Begin TLS negotiation now" as a client**, does  anything change for me as a client in the **futher** communication, that is, the format of the requests and responses, some additional information, etc?
I mean the API level, not the lower levels.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an IMAP protocol question not related to Unix & Linux as defined in the [help].

Comment: What changes is that the communications are therefore encrypted.  Don't expect to manually handle an encrypted connection.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, **as a client** -- does it have to know it's encrypted? why?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I disagree. Understanding protocols commonly used by Unix systems is on-topic here.

Comment: @Gilles: It doesn't seem to fit under any of the [help/on-topic] categories. I don't see how that's really anything but boat Unix, in any case.

Comment: If the question were about, e.g., 9P, then sure, but IMAP has no particular Unix connection. I don't think questions about HTTP headers are on topic either. I could be wrong on both counts, of course, but it'll be strange to be the less expansionist one for once.

Comment: @Johshi:  Your email client tells the server that it wants to start communicating securely, encrypting everything that is sent, which in turn also means that it has to decrypt what is received from the server.  I'm not sure what you're stuck on as this is like asking if you need to understand Chinese to communicate with someone whom you just told you speak Chinese.

Answer (score 3):

The `STARTLS` process tells the client and server to start negotiating an encrypted connection, so all further data will be TLS (SSL, close enough) encrypted.  This will prevent people from sniffing your traffic (eg usernames, passwords).

Now some servers can be configured to provide different services; for example an IMAP server may refuse to allow the LOGIN command over a plain connection but will allow it over a TLS encrypted connection.

We can see the difference.  In this example, for a normal IMAP connect we are shown:

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED] Dovecot ready.
```

Note the "LOGINDISABLED" part.

If we connect to the same server via TLS

```
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE AUTH=PLAIN
```

Now we can see "AUTH" is available, so I can attempt a login.

IMAP isn't the only service that may work this way; eg SMTP with plain connections:

```
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

And with TLS

```
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

Again there's a new `AUTH` command available.

Comment: I already know that.

Comment: Then what is your question?  These commands _are_ the API layer.

Comment: What becomes different after

Comment: And that's what I described.  What _type_ of differences are you looking for?

Comment: Man, what are trying to convince me in?

Comment: You can think of your answer as of a perfect one, that won't change anything, I won't accept it.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're looking for so I can add that to the answer.

Comment: @Johshi I'm with Stephen: this answer describes what STARTTLS changes, this is exactly what you asked. If this is not what you meant to ask, you need to ask a new question that clearly explains what you mean to ask.

Comment: @Gilles, see my update.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: @Johshi I think the answer to your update is “nothing else changes”. The protocol over the TLS layer is exactly the IMAP protocol, but over TLS (which itself is over TCP) instead of over TCP. That is, Stephen's answer is complete. He doesn't describe other changes because there are no other changes.

Comment: @Gilles, than that's the only thing that should've been in the answer.